# In laravel, check referrer before login page and show nothing if redirect referrer is not from a specific url

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-9

I would like to give access to the site if it is redirected from a specific url. If not from that url, site will not show any view or **This site can’t be reached** page. I know I can use one of these to check the referrer.

```
    $request->header('HTTP_REFERRER')
    Request::server('HTTP_REFERER');
    request()->headers->get('referer');
    Request::header('referer');
    url()->previous();
```

But I don't know where should I put this. Where is the main entry point of the application? As I would like to allow user to see the site after checking the referrer, otherwise no view at all, not even the login page.It would be better to have an example.

Comment: I'd suggest middleware, https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/middleware

Answer (score 0):

You can create a Middleware in app/Http/Middleware :

```php
class ReferrerMiddleware
{
    public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next)
    {
        // TODO : check stuff about referrer here and display a specific view if it doesn't match expected

        // If it matches expected continue
        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

And then register your Middleware in web or/and api group app/Http/Kernel.php :

```php
        'web' => [
            // Others middleware applied to web group
            \App\Http\Middleware\ReferrerMiddleware::class
        ],
```